# Sound Issue - Dummy Output/Suspended State

Tags: sound, suspend, pulseaudio, alsa

I'm currently facing an issue with the sound on my Ubuntu system and could really use some assistance in troubleshooting it.
My sound output device is stuck in a "SUSPENDED" state and is identified as "auto_null," which seems to be a dummy output. This occurs even though my sound hardware is connected properly.

Steps Taken So Far:

- Restarted PulseAudio using the command `pulseaudio -k`.
- Checked ALSA mixer (not running).
- Ensured my Ubuntu system is up to date with the latest updates.

System Details:

Comment: What hardware are you using? Are you able to provide your ubuntu and kernel versions?